# How to apply further filter on a collection subset

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am working on a below list of trade objects

```
List<Trades> =
[Fund-A, Broker-A, 100]
[Fund-A, Broker-B, 200]
[Fund-B, Broker-A, 100]   
[Fund-C, Broker-D, 300]   

List<String> = funds basically (list contains unique values)
[Fund-A]
[Fund-B]
```

Expected output passing trades (List) and funds (List)

```
[Fund-A, Broker-A, 100]
[Fund-B, Broker-A, 100]
```

I can perform a simple filter on trades collection that contains any  fund in fund list as below

```
trades.stream().filter(x -> funds.contains(x.getfund())).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But this outputs

```
[Fund-A, Broker-A, 100]
[Fund-A, Broker-B, 200]
[Fund-B, Broker-A, 100]
```

But struggling on how to eliminate/exclude this entry "[Fund-A, Broker-B, 200]" as Fund-B doesn't have an entry against Broker-B in trades.

**Additional Info** 
Thanks for sharing comments. As requested sharing more clarity, output should be any trades with fund present in funds `Set<String>` and also make sure if `[FUND-A, BROKER-A, 100]` is selected there must be an entry for FUND-B that is `[FUND-B, BROKER-A, 100]`

expecting output as

```
    [Fund-A, Broker-A, 100]
    [Fund-B, Broker-A, 100]
```

with `[Fund-A, Broker-B, 200]` EXCLUDED

Comment: The part *as Fund-B doesn't have an entry against Broker-B in trades* is not really clear in the question. Do you mean to select a `Trade` only if its fund is present in the `Set<String>` && it is associated with only `Boker A`?

Comment: Abdul, since it's a bit unclear what you're asking, maybe it would help to write the pseudo code (or even pre-Java 8 code) you'd want to do after the simple filter in your question.  I don't see what criteria you're using to exclude `[Fund-A, Broker-B, 200]`.

Comment: Naman/bphilipnyc - Please refer to additional info section. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand `funds.contains(x.getBroker())`. From your example this filter is never true

Comment: matanper ... good point .. it's typo edited to say x.getfunds()

Answer (score 0):

With few attempts managed to get expected results, welcome feedback to ascertain whether this is good practice/effective way

```
        List<EligibleBroker> possibleEligibles = trades.stream().filter(x -> funds.contains(x.getAcctCd()))
                                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TradeData::getBrokerCd))
                                            .entrySet().stream().map(m -> {
                                                EligibleBroker eligBrk =  new EligibleBroker();
                                                eligBrk.setBrokerCd(m.getKey());
                                                eligBrk.setTarget(m.getValue().get(0).getTarget());
                                                eligBrk.setAcctCd(m.getValue().stream().map(f -> f.getAcctCd()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                                                return eligBrk;
                                            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

// TODO list equals requires fine tunning

        List<EligibleBroker> eligibles = possibleEligibles.stream().filter(e -> e.getAcctCd().equals(funds)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where

```
public class EligibleBroker {
    private List<String> acctCd;
    private String brokerCd;
    private double target;
....
}
```